# SQL Select Statement joining

Tags: php, android, mysql, sql, slim

I have one table of oc_category_description where columns are :

- category_id
- name

and other table oc_category where columns are :

- category_id
- image
- parent_id

Here the sample pic of oc_category_description table

[image]

oc_category table

[image]

Here i am want to show name, category_id, image, parent_id where oc_category parent_id is 0;

Here is sql :

php

```
function getMainCategory()
{
    $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT category_id, image, parent_id, (SELECT oc_category_description.name FROM oc_category_description WHERE oc_category.category_id = oc_category_description.category_id) FROM oc_category WHERE parent_id = 0 ORDER BY category_id ASC");

    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($category_id, $image, $parent_id, $name);

    $users = array();

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $temp = array();
        $temp['category_id'] = $category_id;
        $temp['image'] = $image;
        $temp['parent_id'] = $parent_id;
        $temp['name'] = $name;

        array_push($users, $temp);
    }
    return $users;
}
```

but it returns nothing :(

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Joining query using Selection Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59525900/sql-joining-query-using-selection-statement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Join

```
SELECT ocd.category_id, image, parent_id, name
FROM oc_category_description  AS ocd
INNER JOIN oc_category 
WHERE parent_id = 0 
ORDER BY ocd.category_id ASC
```

Comment: Didn't work. returns nothing :(

Comment: Try change INNER JOIN on LEFT JOIN. If it will not help try select without join and "name". If it still will be without data - think of it.

Answer (score 0):

With an INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT d.category_id, c.image, c.parent_id, d.name
FROM oc_category_description  d INNER JOIN oc_category c
ON c.category_id = d.category_id
WHERE c.parent_id = 0 
ORDER BY d.category_id
```

If you get duplicate rows in the results change to:

```
SELECT DISTINCT...
```

Comment: Didn't work. Result nothing :(

Comment: Then there are not any rows that meet your conditions. Post sample data and expected results.

Comment: edited the question. now please check.