# SQL Joining query using Selection Statement

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I have one table of oc_category_description where columns are :

- category_id
- name

and other table oc_category where columns are :

- category_id
- image
- parent_id

Here the sample pic of oc_category_description table

[image]

oc_category table

[image]

Here i am want to show name, category_id, image, parent_id where oc_category parent_id is 0;

Here is sql :

php

```
function getMainCategory()
{
    $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT category_id, image, parent_id, (SELECT oc_category_description.name FROM oc_category_description WHERE oc_category.category_id = oc_category_description.category_id) FROM oc_category WHERE parent_id = 0 ORDER BY category_id ASC");

    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($category_id, $image, $parent_id, $name);

    $users = array();

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $temp = array();
        $temp['category_id'] = $category_id;
        $temp['image'] = $image;
        $temp['parent_id'] = $parent_id;
        $temp['name'] = $name;

        array_push($users, $temp);
    }
    return $users;
}
```

but it returns nothing :(

Comment: This is the exact duplicate of [a question you have asked previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59518953/sql-select-statement-joining) and it was closed for some reason. Please consider editing that one and make it more clear, instead of posting a new one.

Comment: I edited the previous one but didn't get any solution.

Comment: But it's not a good idea to post duplicate questions. If your edits did not help the readers to have a better understanding of the problem, I guess posting the exact question won't help them either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below script-

```
SELECT oc_category.category_id, 
oc_category.image, 
oc_category.parent_id, 
oc_category_description.name
FROM oc_category 
INNER JOIN oc_category_description 
    ON oc_category.category_id = oc_category_description.category_id
WHERE oc_category.parent_id = 0 
ORDER BY oc_category.category_id ASC
```

Comment: Returns nothing :(

Comment: It should return data. Please check the output for some sample data in the link - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=077ab214190b42b6c681d5eb528b5512

Comment: In my Rest API it returns null

Comment: then the issue is somewhere else not in the query. Even your query should also work but using JOIN for this case is better one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select t1.category_id,t1.image, t1.parent_id, t2.name from oc_category as t1 left join oc_category_discription as t2 on t1.category_id = t2.category_id where t1. parent_id = 0 order by id t1.category_id asc;
```

Comment: Returns Empty :(